# iOS: What is the difference between -init and -viewLoad of a ViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I don't know exactly what's the right place to set things like the tintColor of the NavigationBar or the title of my ViewController. It works in the -init method and the -viewLoad method too. What is the "best-practice" or "right way" to do this? Has one of those any advantages?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `init` methods (yes there is more then one) are where the `UIViewController` is initialized. Thus this is the place where you do stuff for the `UIViewController` and not its views.

If you use a `nib` to load you view then the best place to set any properties is the `viewDidLoad` method. This method gets called after the `nib` is loaded.
If you set up the view programatically use the `loadView` method then this is the place to set `UIControl` properties.

Since the system can unload views to save memory, it will leave the `UIViewController` alone. Any properties set in the `init` methode will not be applied again, since the `UIViewController` is already initialized.

Answer (score 1):

the init method is used to initialize the viewController while viewDidLoad method is used to load your nib(i.e. your view). so when you want to do something with your viewController then use init method and when you want to do something with your view then use viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

The right place is to set it in `viewDidLoad`. To know more about those methods, apple has provided the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms `init` is for preparing data. `viewDidLoad` is for filling data into view.

According to [Apple's Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningYourSubclass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1)

### Initialization methods

**Task**: Allocate **critical data structures** required by your view controller.

**Discussion**: Your custom initialization method (whether it is named init or something else) is always responsible for **putting your view controller object into a known good state**. Use these methods to allocate whatever **data structures** are needed to ensure proper operation.

### viewDidLoad

**Task**: Allocate or load data to be displayed in your view.

**Discussion**: Use the viewDidLoad method to **load any data objects** you intend to display. By the time this method is called, **your view objects are guaranteed to exist** and to be in a known good state.